# How do I fix my lists so I don't have to toggle twice before the icon updates?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-lists

Basically what happens is when I load my page and then drop down either my outer collapsible menu (the `.admin`) or the nested collapsible menu (`.unitsofstudy`), it does not update the glyphicon I have set using the `:after` selector unless I toggle it twice.

Would anyone be able to take a look and see if they can spot where I have screwed this up; I have been at this for a few hours now trying to fix but with no success. If any more info is needed let me know.

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar-collapse" class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 sidebar">
    <ul class="nav menu" id="navmenu-sidebar">
        <!-- Admin dropdown -->
        <li>
            <a class="admin" data-toggle="collapse" href="#admin"><i class="fa fa-tasks" style="margin-right: 16px;"></i>Admin</a>
            <ul id="admin" class="nav collapse">
                <li>
                    <a class="unitsofstudy" data-toggle="collapse" href="#unitsofstudy"> &nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-book" style="margin-right: 12px;"></i>Units of Study</a>
                    <ul id="unitsofstudy" class="nav collapse">
                        <li>
                            <a href="@Url.Content("~/Admin/Units")"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-book" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i> View Units</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="@Url.Content("~/Admin/NewOfferedUnit")"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-plus" style="margin-right: 10px;"></i> Create Unit Offerings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="@Url.Content("~/Admin/NewUnit")"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-plus" style="margin-right: 10px;"></i> Register Units</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="@Url.Content("~/Admin/NewSemester")"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-plus" style="margin-right: 10px;"></i> Register Semesters</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.admin:after, .unitsofstudy:after {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings'; 
    content: "\e114";    
    float: right;       
    color: grey;        
}
.admin.collapsed:after, .unitsofstudy.collapsed:after {
    content: "\e080";   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your anchors an initial class of `.collapsed`

```
<li>
    <a class="admin collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#admin">
        <i class="fa fa-tasks" style="margin-right: 16px;"></i>Admin
    </a>
</li>
```

So class both admin and unitsofstudy to let bootstrap know the initial state of the menu is collapsed

Working example

http://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/pen/6443069430f54e0b635e726c2cb9da02